# How to limit the number of words per line in a html paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a paragraph containing around a 100 words. I want to limit the maximum number of words to `10` per line. I used the width property in css but when the font size is decreased limit exceeds. How can I limit the words per line?   Any help would be appreciated.

Example:

```
<p>The key takeaway for understanding the shift towards VR & AR is their collective push towards enabling people to engage more naturally with computers — by simply looking, gesturing, conversing, and being — as opposed to dealing with interfering and unnatural interfaces like mice, keyboards, and flat screens. Less interference means more immersion. And more immersion means more humanity, empathy, and potential for transformation in our experience — both relating to computers, and to each-other.</p>
```

Output should be a html paragraph with only 10 words per line:

```
The key takeaway for understanding the shift towards VR & 
AR is their collective push towards enabling people to engage 
more naturally with computers — by simply looking, gesturing, conversing, and being — as 
opposed to dealing with interfering and unnatural interfaces like mice, 
keyboards, and flat screens. Less interference means more immersion. And 
more immersion means more humanity, empathy, and potential for transformation 
in our experience — both relating to computers, and to each-other.
```

Comment: Did you try to add a `\n`  each 10 words or something?

Comment: Why don't you substring the text with a for and then put it back together adding \n as dloeda said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this approach, the string is `split` by white space then, in a loop, put together again by white space. Every tenth word is then given a new line.

I'm sure there's a more elegant approach.

```js
var str = 'The key takeaway for understanding the shift towards VR & AR is their collective push towards enabling people to engage more naturally with computers — by simply looking, gesturing, conversing, and being — as opposed to dealing with interfering and unnatural interfaces like mice, keyboards, and flat screens. Less interference means more immersion. And more immersion means more humanity, empathy, and potential for transformation in our experience — both relating to computers, and to each-other.',
  parts = str.split(' '),
  outStr = '';

//Combine each word
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  outStr += ' ' + parts[i];
  
  //every tenth word, add a new-line. Change this to '<br/>' if you want html.
  if ((i + 1) % 10 === 0) {
    outStr += "\n";
  }
}
console.log(outStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something you're looking for. Feel free to replace `\n` with anything you want:

```js
const refineParagraph = ((text, limit, delimiter) => {
  return text.split(' ').reduce((a, b, i) => (i % limit) ? a + ' ' + b : a + ' ' + b + delimiter);
});


let paragraph = 'The key takeaway for understanding the shift towards VR & AR is their collective push towards enabling people to engage more naturally with computers — by simply looking, gesturing, conversing, and being — as opposed to dealing with interfering and unnatural interfaces like mice, keyboards, and flat screens. Less interference means more immersion. And more immersion means more humanity, empathy, and potential for transformation in our experience — both relating to computers, and to each-other.'

let refined = refineParagraph(paragraph, 10, '\n');

console.log(refined);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the input string into an array of words and loop through every word in order to add a new line (Ex. `<br>`) every ten words.

See following example please:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myText");
var words = elem.innerHTML.split(' ');
var wrappedText = '';

words.forEach(function(word, i){
  if(i > 0 && (i+1) % 10 == 0)
    wrappedText += word + '<br>';
  else
    wrappedText += word + ' ';
});

elem.innerHTML = wrappedText;
```

```html
<div id="myText">The key takeaway for understanding the shift towards VR & AR is their collective push towards enabling people to engage more naturally with computers — by simply looking, gesturing, conversing, and being — as opposed to dealing with interfering and unnatural interfaces like mice, keyboards, and flat screens. Less interference means more immersion. And more immersion means more humanity, empathy, and potential for transformation in our experience — both relating to computers, and to each-other.
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Alternative with [`<pre>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) (that keeps indentations, spaces and new lines) and `\n`

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myText");
var words = elem.innerHTML.split(' ');
var wrappedText = '';

words.forEach(function(word, i){
  if(i > 0 && (i+1) % 10 == 0)
    wrappedText += word + '\n';
  else
    wrappedText += word + ' ';
});

elem.innerHTML = wrappedText;
```

```html
<pre id="myText">The key takeaway for understanding the shift towards VR & AR is their collective push towards enabling people to engage more naturally with computers — by simply looking, gesturing, conversing, and being — as opposed to dealing with interfering and unnatural interfaces like mice, keyboards, and flat screens. Less interference means more immersion. And more immersion means more humanity, empathy, and potential for transformation in our experience — both relating to computers, and to each-other.
</pre>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: Is it possible to break the line without using `<br/>`.

Comment: @BharathShetty Yes, you could separate into multiple spans/divs/whatever. And if you mean if it's possible by css only then no it's not possible to match n worlds by css. You can do an overflow but it won't match words.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer, if you prefer you could use the `pre` html tag and break the lines using `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use [`hypenation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) because breaking lines without looking at the meaning could end up generating usability issues.

but, if you just want to break at `10 word occurrence`, you could use a regex:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  var p = document.querySelector('#test');

  p.innerHTML = p.textContent.replace(
    /((?:\S+\s+){10}\S+)/g, '$1<br />'
  );

})
```

```html
<p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ad aliquid assumenda consequatur eligendi ex harum in iure libero molestiae natus repellendus sunt veniam. Ipsa nemo omnis perspiciatis quae sint!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ad aliquid assumenda consequatur eligendi ex harum in iure libero molestiae natus repellendus sunt veniam. Ipsa nemo omnis perspiciatis quae sint!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ad aliquid assumenda consequatur eligendi ex harum in iure libero molestiae natus repellendus sunt veniam. Ipsa nemo omnis perspiciatis quae sint!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ad aliquid assumenda consequatur eligendi ex harum in iure libero molestiae natus repellendus sunt veniam. Ipsa nemo omnis perspiciatis quae sint!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ad aliquid assumenda consequatur eligendi ex harum in iure libero molestiae natus repellendus sunt veniam. Ipsa nemo omnis perspiciatis quae sint!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ad aliquid assumenda consequatur eligendi ex harum in iure libero molestiae natus repellendus sunt veniam. Ipsa nemo omnis perspiciatis quae sint!</p>
```

Comment: This will breaks every 11 words.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
var getString = document.getElementById("string").innerHTML;
var output =  document.getElementsByClassName("output")[0];
var totalWord = getString.split(" ");
for(var i = 0; i < totalWord.length;i++){
    if(i % 10 == 0 && i > 0){
    output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + totalWord[i] + "<br>";
  }else{
  output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + totalWord[i] + " ";
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="string">The key takeaway for understanding the shift towards VR & AR is their collective push towards enabling people to engage more naturally with computers — by simply looking, gesturing, conversing, and being — as opposed to dealing with interfering and unnatural interfaces like mice, keyboards, and flat screens. Less interference means more immersion. And more immersion means more humanity, empathy, and potential for transformation in our experience — both relating to computers, and to each-other.
</p>

<div class="output"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/1f787pw8/